# Use firebug to show me which rails template is being serverd

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firebug

Can firebug be used to show me which rails template is currently being viewed along with the method in the controller that calls the view in question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of the box no.

But, you could send messages to Firebug from your serverside by returning console messages.  You could put this perhaps in your layout application.html.erb for every request.

```
# application.html.erb
<script>
console.log("Controller: <%= controller.controller_name %>");
console.log("Action: <%= controller.action_name %>");
</script>
```

[image]

http://getfirebug.com/logging

Answer (score 2):

No, but this is what I typically do with my rails code to give me access to this info:

```
<body class='<%= "#{Rails.env} #{params[:controller]} #{params[:action]}" %>'>
```

This also allows me to override global styles at a controler#action level too (Bounus!)

Answer (score 1):

If you can see rails development log, it will tell you which layout/view/partial is rendered. The text looks like:

```
Rendered controller_names/new.html.erb within layouts/application (0.4ms)
```